# The allowed underlying container for a "queue"

Tags: c++

What are the allowed underlying container for a queue?

in the following syntax:

```
queue<int, list<int> > q;
```

is list the only allowed one? (among list, deque, vector)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[C++11 N3485](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) § 23.6.3.1/1 says this:

> Any sequence container supporting operations front(), back(), push_back() and pop_front() can be
>   used to instantiate queue. In particular, list (23.3.5) and deque (23.3.3) can be used.

So as long as it's a sequence container and has the appropriate member functions, it will work.  However, operations are delegated to the underlying container, so one should keep that in mind when there are performance requirements.

Comment: But `vector` has no pop_front.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, Then `vector` can't be used. I didn't see that edit yet, but I'll fix it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.